# How to hide a tag with ng-hide when the tag is empty (contains no text)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide every tag which has no content (simple text) using ng-hide directive.
Here's what I am trying to accomplish:
`<div class="menu-head" ng-hide="c1.section == ''">{{c1.section}}</div>`
But this doesn't work. However, the following two evaluate to true (for testing purposes I set the c1.section field to the value of 'Section 1') and the respective div becomes hidden:
`<div class="menu-head" ng-hide="c1.section == c1.section">{{c1.section}}</div>`
`<div class="menu-head" ng-hide="c1.section == 'Section 1'">{{c1.section}}</div>`
The c1.section is accessed via

```
<div ng-repeat="c1 in col1">
```

from this controller:

```
function MenuCtrl($scope) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.col1 = MenuData.col1;
    $scope.col2 = MenuData.col2;
    $scope.col3 = MenuData.col3;
}
```

Where the object col1 may, or may not contain the field 'section'. So obviously whenever a field (any field) is missing from the object, I want its div to be missing/not showing in the DOM. Here's the MenuData object:

```
var MenuData = {
    col1: [
        {section: 'Section 1'}, // <-here the fields id, name, price and descr are missing so their divs must not show up in the DOM.
        {
            id: '1',
//            section: 'Section 2', <- here the field section is missing (commented-out).
            name: 'Position 1',
            price: '2.50',
            descr: 'some description'
        },
        {section: 'Section 3'},
        {
            id: '2',
            section: 'Section 4',
            name: 'Position 2',
            price: '4.75',
            descr: ''
        }
    ]
};
```

How do I make the expression of ng-hide to evaluate to 'true' when there is no content in 'c1.section' data binding?

Comment: What's `c1.section`? What do you set it to initially? Is it 'empty string' or is it perhaps undefined?

Comment: Can you just use `ng-show` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
<div ng-hide="!c1.section">
```

This will hide the `div` when `c1.section` equals `''` or when the `c1` object doesn't have a `section` property.

I have created a working Plnkr for your convenience at http://plnkr.co/edit/aOe7Vc8lmYf43ODkCymx?p=preview

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic! Works as it should. Now that I see the solution, it seems so obvious. Silly me. :)

Comment: How to use this if the HTML table is empty?

Comment: This was a life saver - thank you - worked like a charm